# Flexbuilder plugin install fails to detect eclipse directory

Tags: installation, eclipse, flexbuilder

I'm attempting to install the Flexbuilder eclipse plugin.  After I've selected the eclipse directory (verified to be the correct directory multiple times) I get the following error:

> Please choose an existing Eclipse 3.2,
>   3.3, or 3.4 root folder to be extended
>
> This root folder must contain the
>   subfolder named "configuration".

The eclipse folder I'm using does have that folder.  I'm able to force it to continue the install, but eclipse doesn't have the plugin installed.

Is there any way to get around this?  Some way to make eclipse see it after the install is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker figured out the solution.

In eclipse's link directory was a file called `com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.core.link` that contained the path to the plugin.  Adding `path=` to the beginning of it fixed the issue.